# Error on converting Datatype to INT in JSP

Tags: jsp, type-conversion

I recieved Data from a form via POST/GET method in a page. Now, by default, JSP takes that as string. I wanted to convert it to int and tried but it not worked.

My JSP Code for this is:

```
String editstr=request.getParameter("some_thing");
int edit;
edit=Integer.parseInt(editstr)
```

I also tried something like

```
int edit=Integer.parseInt(editstr)
```

Neither Works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *must* have to test the parameter whether it is null or not.

```
String editstr=request.getParameter("some_thing");
int edit=0;
if(editstr!=null){
   try{
     edit=Integer.parseInt(editstr);
   }catch(Exception ex) { 
     out.println(ex);
   }
}
```

PS: You should have to learn/use JSTL to [avoid Java code in JSPs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files).

Answer (score 1):

Do you get [NumberFormatException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) or [NullPointerException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)?

If not then look for an trouble in setting and getting the parameter `some_thing`.